# How to stream zipped file (on the fly) via Play Framework 2.5 in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, zip, akka, akka-stream

I want to stream some files and zip them on the fly, so users can download multiple files into a single zipped file without writing anything to the local disk. However, my current implementation holds everything in the memory, and will no work for large files. Is there any way to fix it?

I was looking at this implementation: https://gist.github.com/kirked/03c7f111de0e9a1f74377bf95d3f0f60, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

```
 import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream}
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipOutputStream}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{StreamConverters}
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class HomeController extends Controller {
  def single() = Action {
                         Ok.sendFile(
                           content = new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
                           fileName = _ => "a.csv"
                         )
                       }

  def zip() = Action {
                     Ok.chunked(StreamConverters.fromInputStream(fileByteData)).withHeaders(
                       CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/zip",
                       CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename = test.zip"
                     )
                   }

  def fileByteData(): ByteArrayInputStream = {
    val fileList = List(
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
      new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\b.csv")
    )

    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(baos))

    try {
      fileList.map(file => {
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.toPath.getFileName.toString))
        zos.write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
        zos.closeEntry()
      })
    } finally {
      zos.close()
    }

    new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to buffer the contents in an array then putting them into a `ByteArrayInputStream` you could use Java's piping mechanism.

Here's a sketch solution:

```
def zip() = Action {
  // Create Source that listens to an OutputStream
  // and pass it to `fileByteData` method.
  val zipSource: Source[ByteString, Unit] =
    StreamConverters
      .asOutputStream()
      .mapMaterializedValue(fileByteData)
  Ok.chunked(zipSource).withHeaders(
    CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/zip",
    CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename = test.zip")
}

// Send the file data, given an OutputStream to write to.
def fileByteData(os: OutputStream): Unit = {
  val fileList = List(
    new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\a.csv"),
    new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\b.csv")
  )

  val zos = new ZipOutputStream(os)
  val buffer: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](2048)
  try {
    for (file <- fileList) {
      zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.toPath.getFileName.toString))
      val fis = new Files.newInputStream(file.toPath)
      try {
        @tailrec
        def zipFile(): Unit = {
          val bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)
          if (bytesRead == -1) () else {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            zipFile()
          }
        }
        zipFile()
      } finally fis.close()
      zos.closeEntry()
    }
  } finally {
    zos.close()
  }
}
```

This is just an outline of an approach. You'll also want to make sure:
- the threading is OK - the `fileByteData` will hopefully run on a different thread to the sending thread
- the error handling is OK - e.g. all streams are closed properly if there's an error on either the server (e.g. file not found) or client side (early disconnect)

Comment: Thanks a lot! changing the "Source" to "StreamConverts" in "Source.asOutputStream().mapMaterializedValue(fileByteData)" compiles for me. However, with this implementation, I'm getting IllegalStateException. After using a byte array buffer to read the file, the illegalStateException is gone, but the file is never downloaded..

Comment: OK I've updated the snippet so it compiles. What's throwing the `IllegalStateException`?

Comment: It's the "zos.write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))". After I replace it with "val buffer: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](2048)
        val bis = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file.toPath))
        var bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
          zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
          bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)
        }" the exception is gone. But the zip folder is not downloaded.

Comment: Oops totally forgot about `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)` reading each file into memory with a buffer. I've updated the code based partly on your while loop. Do you want to check with that? Also which class was throwing the `IllegalStateException`?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Promise already completed.
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
  atscala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.failure(Promise.scala:104)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.failure(Promise.scala:153)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:257)`

Comment: `at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExec
utor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.sc
ala:91)`

Comment: The above IllegalException was when we used the `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)`

Comment: OK - so that exception's gone now? Is the file being downloaded?

Comment: Oh the exception is gone. But the file is still not downloaded. It just hangs there.

Comment: Can you try running `fileByteData`'s body in a new thread with `ExecutionContext.run`?

Comment: Ah after I replace the file with s3 file, it works! I think it's the thread issue. Thank you!!!!!!! :))))

Comment: So it works now using an s3 file. Did you also use `ExecutionContext.run` to fix the thread issue? Let me know - I'll update the snippet in the answer.

Comment: Now it's not working with even s3 files :( Could you update the answer so I know how to fix it with the `ExecutionContext.run`.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm looking at this post for why it's not downloading https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7512

Comment: Right, I remember the threading of the code calling the `OutputStream` being a possible issue. I'll link back to this SO answer from that issue to help those using Google. :)

Comment: I'm trying `.mapMaterializedValue(os => Future { fileByteData(os); os.close();pringln("os is closed")}` with implicit excecutionContext.global. The I see the folder was downloaded with the "starting" label but never moves forward beyond that. I also can't reach the print statement indicating that the os is closed properly. Am I doing anything wrong here?